# Change FBSDKLoginButton text - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

[Image of my button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmGaS.png)

Here's my problem, I'm currently developing a french IOS application and I need to use a Facebook connection. 
I want to change to FBSDKLoginButton text ("Log in with Facebook") to something else ("Se connecter avec Facebook") in french but I don't know how.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Show the snap of code which you are using. You can also create a button with any text and after that calling the function to login with facebook.

Comment: I create a button with FBSDKLoginButton class. If I create a button with any text, how can I have the FB logo on it ? Thanks

Comment: You have to add image for it.

Comment: Just added it to my post

Comment: Now u can set the background image for this button. Which you want.

Comment: The button is linked to FBSDKLoginButton so whatever I write inside isn't visible. The result is always the same whatever I do : "Log in with Facebook"